# Expload Separator Array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have an code from database like

```
$exp = ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam;
```

i want to make an array like

```
$ukuran = array("33", "34", "35");
$warna = array("putih","hitam");
```

i have try to use explode but i have trouble result.

```
explode(";",$exp);
```

the result like

```
 Array
(
    [0] => ukuran:33,34,35
    [1] => warna:putih,hitam
    [2] => 
)
```

Anyone can help me, how to explode this case please?

Comment: Is your database normalised?  Holding data like this sounds like your cramming data into fields where you should have separate tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam;';
$string = str_replace(['ukuran:', 'warna:'], '', $string);
$exploded = explode(';', $string);
$ukuran = explode(',', $exploded[0]);
$warna = explode(',', $exploded[1]);
```

If you want to do it dynamically you can't create variables but you can create an array with the types as keys:

```
$string = 'ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam;';
$exploded = explode(';', $string);

$keysAndValues = [];

foreach($exploded as $exp) {
    if (strlen($exp) > 0) {
        $key = substr($exp, 0, strpos($exp, ':' ) );
        $values = substr($exp, strpos($exp, ':' ) + 1, strlen($exp) );
        $values = explode(',', $values);
        $keysAndValues[$key] = $values;
    }

}
```

This will output:

```
array (size=2)
  'ukuran' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '33' (length=2)
      1 => string '34' (length=2)
      2 => string '35' (length=2)
  'warna' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'putih' (length=5)
      1 => string 'hitam' (length=5)
```

Call them like this:

```
var_dump($keysAndValues['ukuran']);
var_dump($keysAndValues['warna']);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is like i want, but how if dynamic on string like `size:33,34,35;color:putih,hitam;material:linen,cotton;` automatic check variant before

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say continue as you are, then with your array in your result, loop through each item in the array and store it like so

```
$string = 'ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam;';
$exploded = explode(';',$string);
$master = [];

foreach($exploded as $key => $foo){
    $namedKey = explode(':',$foo);
    $bar = substr($foo, strpos($foo, ":") + 1); //Get everything after the ; character
    $master[$namedKey[0]] = explode(",",$bar);
}
```

This should return a result something along the lines of

```
array(3) {
  ["ukuran"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "33"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "34"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "35"
  }
  ["warna"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "putih"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "hitam"
  }
}
```

Comment: `ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam` is on string but i like your code sir, so dynamic.

Comment: @AndyAjhisRamadhan thanks! If its all on one line, explode it first with your code `explode(";",$exp);` and store the result in a variable then run my code?

Comment: Would it be useful to use the bit before the : as the index for the data?  So you have `ukuran =>[ 33, 34, 35], warna => ['putih'...`

Comment: Sure thx u sir, but how i got name of `ukuran` and `warna` cause they are dynamic name.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir @S_R. :)

Comment: @AndyAjhisRamadhan No problem! Although if you used my answer you've accepted the wrong one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match words and numbers separate.
Then use array_filter to remove the empty values.

```
$exp = "ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam";

Preg_match_all("/(\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)/", $exp, $matches);

Unset($matches[0]);
$matches[1] = array_filter($matches[1]);
$matches[2] = array_filter($matches[2]);
Var_dump($matches);
```

https://3v4l.org/cREn7

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways to do what you want, But If I were you then I'll try this way :)

```
<?php
$exp = 'ukuran:33,34,35;warna:putih,hitam';
$result = explode(';',$exp);
foreach($result as $k=>$v){
    $key_value = explode(':',$v);
    // this line will help your to treat your $ukuran and $warna as array variable
    ${$key_value[0]} = explode(',',$key_value[1]); 
}
print '<pre>';
print_r($ukuran);
print_r($warna);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BAaCT